# Event driven model in Golang

Tags: for-loop, go, rabbitmq, message-queue, event-driven

I am reading [RabbitMQ tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-go.html) and seeing following code:

```
forever := make(chan bool)

go func() {
  for d := range msgs {
    log.Printf("Received a message: %s", d.Body)
  }
}()

log.Printf(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C")
<-forever
```

What I am interested in is `for d := range msgs`. How does this for loop handle events? eg. At the app start I have only one message in `msgs` queue buffer.

**Questions:**

1. How would it process next event?
2. After some [playing around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47477206/rpc-with-golang-and-rabbitmq) with this code I found that it could stuck on `log.Printf` line and wouldn't process events anymore. What can be a reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. How would it process next event?

Beside iteration over basic data structures, [range](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/4) in GoLang can also iterate over values received from a channel. Range iterates over each element as it's received from queue and ends only when the channel is closed. 
The next iteration will happen when the channel (msgs) will receive a value

```
msgs <- message
```

> 2. After some playing around with this code I found that it could stuck on log.Printf line and wouldn't process events anymore. What can be a reason?

Considering that there is a [blocking channel](https://gobyexample.com/channel-synchronization) `forever` and we have a range that iterates over the `msgs` channel there are 2 possible actions that are expected:

Either

1. send message through the msgs channel

   msgs <- message

or

2. send value to `forever` so it unblocks the process

   forever <- false

It seems like the solution is designed to **wait** and asynchronously process messages through a channel.